# Where did the darkness come from?

Tags: exegesis, creation

In the beginning God said "let there be light" and there was light. And God saw that the light was good. Then God separated the light form the darkness. **Where did the darkness come from?** I do not have my Bible with me so my quotes my not be verbatim.

Comment: did you read the whole chapter in Genesis?

Answer (score 3):

The darkness appears to have been there from the beginning:

> the earth was without form or shape, **with darkness over the abyss** and a mighty wind sweeping over the water
>
> Genesis 1:2, NABRE

Answer (score 1):

> “I form light and create darkness; I make well-being and create calamity; I am the Lord, who does all these things.”
>   ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭45:7‬ ‭ESV‬‬

If you have any doubt God created darkness. He says as much.

—————————-

I sense I need to add some details about this darkness because it’s not being interpreted from a Biblical stand point but pseudoscientific dogma, which has not been proven. Also western thinking tend to categorize things into good and bad, but light and dark are not good and bad, they are necessary scales on a balance, they bring equilibrium.

Darkness according to God has within it hidden treasures that can be found no where else but in darkness.

> “And I will give thee **the treasures of darkness**, and hidden riches of secret places, that thou mayest know that I, the Lord, which call thee by thy name, am the God of Israel.”
>   ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭45:3‬ ‭KJV‬‬

Darkness is not evil. Darkness is darkness and sometimes we are required to be in darkness, living godly lives trusting God shrouded with darkness and refusing to light our own lights to ease the frustration of being in the dark.

> “Who is among you that feareth the Lord, that obeyeth the voice of his servant, **that walketh in darkness**, and hath no light? let him trust in the name of the Lord, and stay upon his God.”
>   ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭50:10‬ ‭KJV‬‬

Yes in this verse it’s not speaking of physical darkness but being in ignorance of some knowledge.

God lives in darkness and furthermore, desires to live in thick darkness.

> “Then spake Solomon, **The Lord said** that he would dwell in the thick darkness.”
>   ‭‭1 Kings‬ ‭8:12‬ ‭KJV‬‬

God says ultimately that darkness is good.

> “And God saw **every thing that he had made**, and, behold, it was very good. And the evening and the morning were the sixth day.”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭1:31‬ ‭KJV‬‬

Even if you want to argue that darkness is not created or a thing, He still separated it from light, called it night and says it was very good.

Comment: I am not sure that such a passage can be understood so literally.  Does God literally create (and so is responsible for) calamity or does He permit circumstances to create such things?  For example, does God also have evil spirits to send people (1 Sam 16:14, 19:9, 18:10, 1 Kings 22:23, 2 Chron 18:22, Judges 9:23, etc).  be careful not to accuse God of creating sin.

Comment: Considering Job’s issue with the sin of pride cause by his own self-righteousness, in the divine council God begged the question of the Accuser. So who instigated what was to follow, all the destruction and loss? Consider also Ahab, was it not God who started by saying Ahab’s time is up, how shall we convince him to go to battle that he may die in battle? It was Ahab’s sins that caused God to bring judgment and likewise for Job or King Saul or whomever but God created the calamity. He gave permission to the evil spirits at His behest.  He uses both vessels of honor and dishonor. He uses them.

Comment: I don’t understand why you are conflating creating calamity with creating sin. The calamity created is in direct response to sin. He says that. It’s not correct to misrepresent or redefine the passage to say what it never actually says nor implies. “Everyone who is proud in heart is an abomination to the LORD; Assuredly, he will not be unpunished.”
‭‭Proverbs‬ ‭16:5‬ ‭NASB‬‬
How do you think He punishes if not by creating calamity in response to their already committed pride or sin? God isn’t sinning or creating the sin by punishing the already committed sin! Where does it say He causes sin?

Comment: What about the Lord's Prayer, "lead us not into temptation".  We must be quite careful about who is doing the tempting.  My references above are literally (but not idiomatically) clear that God sends evil and lying spirits to some.  1 Sam 16:14, 19:9, 18:10, 1 Kings 22:23, 2 Chron 18:22, Judges 9:23, etc.

Comment: Yes God did send them in response to an already committed sin and not as a means of temptation. The sin has already been committed and God is enacting judgment. Someone who is unforgiving will be handed over to the tormentors until they forgive. That literally means that God will allow an unclean spirit to torment those who refuse to forgive. If sins are committed due to the tormentors tormenting it’s still as a result of the initial sin of unforgiveness. God isn’t tempting the unforgiving individual He is tormenting him for refusing to forgive. And his consequent sins are still his own fault.

Comment: Agreed.  That is why 2 Sam 24:1 says God tempted David, while 1 Chron 21:1 says Satan tempted David.  That is, Bible writers often attributed a cause to God that He did not prevent.  Theologically, this is called the "Divine Passive".

Comment: Also in response to sin, in this case David’s sin.

Answer (score 0):

**Where did the darkness come from?**

> Then God said, “Let there be light”; and there was light.  And God saw the light, that it was good; and God divided the light from the darkness. God called the light Day, and the darkness He called Night. So the evening and the morning were the first day. - [(Genesis 1:3-5)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%201&version=NKJV)

This is a very interesting question because we can see that God created all things, but darkness is not mentioned as light is in the first Book of Genesis as God says "Light be" but he does not say "darkness be." **But in creating light, God certainly created darkness, for where the light was absent, there would be darkness**, for God created all from nothing (*creatio ex nihilo*).

> Everything starts with a dark and watery primeval state. Creation involves God organizing the waters and putting them in place so that life can flourish.
>
> **God says "Light be" but he does not say "darkness be."**
>
> God divides the waters into the waters above (kept at bay by a solid sky dome) and from the waters below (the seas), and the seas from the land. In this way God creates the sky, the sea, and the land as distinct zones. God organizes creation by moving water around; however, God does not create water.
>
> This suspicion is reinforced by the way in which most OT scholars (though not all) translate the opening of Genesis: Something like this—"In the beginning of God's creating the heavens and the earth, the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep . . ." In other words, ***creatio ex nihilo*** has many theological merits (and I am not suggesting that the Church abandon it) but it is very likely that Genesis 1 does not teach it. The interests of Genesis lie elsewhere.
>
> So it seems that in Genesis 1 (and that's all I'm talking about here) darkness and water are not so much brought into existence as contained and funneled to serve divine purposes. They are not evil but they are only declared "good" by God when they have been constrained and given a functional role in the cosmos.
>
> So there, woven into the very fabric of the good created order, are the remnants of primeval darkness and chaotic seas — under divine control but dangerous none the less (as Noah's flood shows). - [Did God create the darkness and the sea?](http://theologicalscribbles.blogspot.com/2013/10/did-god-create-darkness-and-sea.html)

Comment: The point is in the beginning God the Father had no one to love except Himself and His angels. (angels do not have the FUNDEMENTAL OPTION). God is LOVE . One can see He had to create an entity who was DIFFERENT than Himself in order to be able to LOVE. The angels were spirits with out the Fundamental option. Since God is HOLY he had to create something that is a direct opposite. LIGHT/DARKNESS. This allows the creation of entities who are free to choose God or choose "NOT GOD". This is where the all pervasive  PAIRS OF OPPOSITES in space-time comes from. The Hegelian dialectic construct. david

Comment: @David Your question seems to only deal with the physical aspect of darkness. The Angels and their fall is a different matter. I see where you are going, but that is a whole different question dealing with God creating beings of free will and god creating an abyss of darkness for those who sinned against God's love.

Comment: God the Father had God the Son and God the Holy Spirit to love.

Comment: @David prior to the beginning there was God and the Word, who was God. That there is two persons. The Bible mentions a third the Spirit of God. Three persons prior to the Beginning, just as it reads in the Hebrew Elohim (Gods - plural) eth (The Word). Therefore God has three persons who could love one another with divine love. Elohim is echâd and not yachid. God is united and not singular. Angels come after the beginning. I would recommend you invest in some Hebrew lessons or at least research the Elohim and El, echâd and yachid.

Comment: The Father and the son "are one", and the Spirit is also incorporated into this "I THAT IS WE". God (the trinity) needed some entity different and separate from Himself (themselves) to love. The link between Christ and his Father is described as ONE but also Jesus in talking with the Jews about his not judging men, states that he can do so because God is his Father and that gives Jewish law the TWO WITNESS necessary in legal matters. (i.e. from John's Gospel ) David

Comment: My wife and I are one (echâd) we are both one (united) and separate persons. Likewise the Father and Son are echâd (one or united) and separate persons at the same time. So it seems you are getting your theology from an uninspired translation and not the inspired original. Ok, that is everything I need to know proceeding forward. Thank you. Hope you find whatever you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer from the point of view of physics: Darkness is not a thing. It is merely the absence of light. So it does not need to be created. Wherever God did not put any of the light that He created, there would be darkness. If God had never created light at all (but had created space) then there would be darkness everywhere.

EDIT: A comment complained about my use of physics rather than Christian doctrine. I tend not to distinguish between the various sources of truth, especially when science solves what appears to be a theological problem. To support without physics my claim that darkness is not a thing but merely the absence of light, let me quote St. Augustine: "where light is not, darkness must needs be" [City of God, Book XI, Ch.9]. So before the creation of light, there was necessarily darkness, without any need for God to create it.

Comment: If you think this is the best answer to the question, then please vote to close the question rather than answer it. We're only after answers that come from Christian Doctrine, not physics.   Also, please use chat rather than go back and forth in comments.